# The value 'jammy' is invalid for APT::Default-Release

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-center

I've run into installation errors when upgrading packages and release of Ubuntu 22.10.

The details are listed below:

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release

= Welcome to Ubuntu 23.04 'Lunar Lobster' =

The Ubuntu team is proud to announce Ubuntu 23.04 'Lunar Lobster'.

...

Continue [yN] y
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                                        
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,260 kB]                                                                                                                                               
Fetched 1,261 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                              
authenticate 'lunar.tar.gz' against 'lunar.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'lunar.tar.gz'
can't load 22.04 (No module named 'DistUpgrade.22')
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lmzh0l52/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewGtk3.py", line 540, in _handleException
    apport_crash(type, value, tb)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lmzh0l52/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeApport.py", line 57, in apport_crash
    apport_excepthook(type, value, tb)
TypeError: apport_excepthook() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exc_tb'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lmzh0l52/lunar", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lmzh0l52/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    save_system_state(logdir)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lmzh0l52/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 125, in save_system_state
    clone.save_state(sourcedir="/", target=target, with_dpkg_status=True,
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lmzh0l52/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 154, in save_state
    self._write_state_installed_pkgs(sourcedir, tar)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lmzh0l52/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 192, in _write_state_installed_pkgs
    cache = self._cache_cls(rootdir=sourcedir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 214, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
apt_pkg.Error: E:The value 'jammy' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

I've tried to solve the problem by modifying apt::default release but I didn't find the release file ''don't have release file''

please help me how to pass this hurdle

Comment: You can edit out all the PR junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although the original question was written as a trial to downgrade the version, I received the same output when I tried to upgrade also
I've succeeded in solving this problem with the assistance of ai sage of Poe
it guided me to install Synaptic package manager
`sudo apt install synaptic`
which is available on the universal repository of Ubuntu
then I selected the installed packages, by clicking status button and using ctrl+a to choose all packages
then I marked them to reinstall by clicking on package droplist and clicking on mark to reinstall
then I rebooted the system to complete the process after the reinstall was finished
then I used full upgrade command several times with rebooting in between till finished `sudo apt full-upgrade`
when all these steps are completed the system was upgraded to version 2304
Best regards

Comment: No thanks for your aggressive language
I've already tried all formatting I can
then all of it are deleted when I published my post, as what appear for me in your comment
If you want to advise others, use proper language
If you don't accept some comments or answers, I think that the platform gave you the choice of downvote
KEEP YOUR PUBLIC ENMITY FOR YOURSELF

Answer (score 1):

You can only upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04 from Ubuntu 22.10. Going backwards from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) is not upgrading, it's downgrading. That's why you got this error message: `The value 'jammy' is invalid for APT::Default-Release`.

If you want to downgrade from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 22.04 the safest way to do it is by backing up your data and fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: thank you for your advice
i got this message also when trying to upgrade
I succeeded in solving the problem and will share the steps below